# How to add Cascading Parameter base on the first paramter select ssrs 2008 report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reporting

[image]

Hi there,

I have a question about how to display parameter base on the first parameter selected value.
for my case , the first parameter Search by has 2 values are
 1. CustomerId =1,
 2. LastName =2

> 1. When user select customerId the parameter customerId text box will display for user to enter customerId
> 2. When user select lastName the lastName textbox will display for user to enter lastname  when user     enter lastName the Name parameter
>      will show dropdown list customer firstName and lastName which who
>      lastName match with the parameter @lastname.

```
Here is my data set for the Name parameter  

> select id,firstName +' - '+lastName  Name  from Customers  Where
> lastName =@LastName  and mergedTo is null  order by lastName
```

Purpose of this my customer wanted to be able to search from lastName but lastName is not a unique i have to created another dropdown list CustomerName to show customer who has match with the parameter @lastName for the user to select one customer which they want to lookup.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, your question is how to populate the `Name` drop down with all the names on selecting the 'LastName`. True?

Comment: I wanted all the parameter hide except the first one Search By has two value 1. CustomerID 2. LastName. when user select CustomerID the parameter CustomerID textbox will display or if user select LastName the lastName textbox display when enter Lastname the parameter dropdowlist Name will display customer who has last name match with the Lastname that user entered.

Comment: Not an answer, but this will have most of the info you need.  http://bisherryli.com/2011/05/28/ssrs-51-using-parameters-in-ssrs-cascading-parameter-2/

Comment: Yes the above link needs to be implemented to suit your requirement.

Comment: @MC_A yes I got till that. But as you said, many people might have the same last name. So you want the name textbox to be populated with all those names which have last name = @lastname?

Comment: Sourav_Agasti  yes, I already make it work on this part. the part i still working on are hide the customerId, LastName  parameter and it will show base on what user select on the first parameter.

Answer (score 0):

There are only 2 options for showing a Parameter: 
Hide Parameter / Show Parameter.

As far as I know there is no way to do an expression based visibility of a Parameter.